# How can I simulate baxter in MoveIt without a real baxter?

Tags: robotic-arm

I follow the tutorials  [Rethink Robotics MoveIt tutorial](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial) to install my baxter with MoveIt. When I run

```
$ ./baxter.sh
```

It shows:

> EXITING - Please edit this file, modifying the 'baxter_hostname' variable to reflect Baxter's current hostname.

I don't have a real baxter robot,how can I simulate it with MoveIt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use the Baxter simulation, you need to first download and install the simulation framework according to the instructions at

http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation

Once you've done that, you'll have to replace the baxter.sh line in your MoveIt command with this command

```
/baxter.sh sim
```